# ASP.NET: ICollection Constructor Not Found?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application running on a remote web server and I just started getting this error.  I can't seem to reproduce it in my development environment:

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1..ctor()'.
```

Could this be due to some misconfiguration of .NET Framework or IIS 6?

Update:
I disassembled the code in the DLL and it seems like the compiler is incorrectly optimizing the code.  (Note that Set is a class that implements a set of unique objects.  It inherits from IEnumerable.)  This line:

```
Set<int> set = new Set<int>();
```

Is compiled into this line:

```
Set<int> set = (Set<int>) new ICollection<CalendarModule>();
```

The Calendar class is a totally unrelated class!!  Has anyone ever noticed .NET incorrectly compiling code like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in the aspnet merge tool which incorrectly merged optimized assemblies.  It can be solved by either not merging the assemblies or not optimizing them.

Answer (score 1):

Are the .NET versions on both systems the same inc. the same service pack?

Answer (score 0):

Is your IIS setup to use .NET 2.0?  If not, change it to 2.0.  If you can't see 2.0 in the list then you'll need to run aspnet_regiis from the 2.0 framework directory.